# Can not get Superfish menu to work on ASPDotNetStoreFront Site

Tags: jquery, asp.net, superfish

I am attempting to use the [Superfish jQuery plugin](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) on our new ASPDotNetStoreFront site, but I can't seem to get it to work. Our site is: http://saiedmusic.aspdotnetstorefront.active-e.net/default.aspx

I get these errors in Firebug:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error   
<!DOCTYPE html>
superfish.js (line 6)

TypeError: jQuery(...).superfish is not a function
jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
saiedm...e-e.net (line 270)
```

This is coming from a `.ascx` template file.

My question is if this is actually some sort of weird way that the site is not pulling in the script?

I know in some cases a blank `<script src=" ">` can throw that error, but it appears to be coming from the Javascript file itself.

```
<%@ Control Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="AspDotNetStorefront.TemplateBase" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ComponentArt" Namespace="ComponentArt.Web.UI" Assembly="ComponentArt.Web.UI" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>(!METATITLE!)</title>
    (!CURRENCY_LOCALE_ROBOTS_TAG!)
    <meta name="description" content="(!METADESCRIPTION!)" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="(!METAKEYWORDS!)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="skins/skin_(!SKINID!)/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="skins/skin_(!SKINID!)/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Top Drop -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/superfish.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="skins/Skin_3/js/superfish.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
    <!-- End Top Drop -->

    <link href="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/bjqs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/js/jquery.secret-source.min.js"></script>

    <!--Product Reviews Block:Reference-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/colorbox.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/ratingpopup.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/ratingstyle.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/imageViewer.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="skins/skin_(!SKINID!)/js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <!--End Product Reviews Block: Reference-->

    <!-- Mini Cart -->
    <link href="skins/skin_1/minicart-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/js/newminicart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/js/vortxajax.js"></script>
    <!-- End Mini Cart -->
    <!--Product Page GZoom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skins/Skin_(!SKINID!)/gzoom.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--end Product Page GZoom -->
    <!-- <script type="text/jscript">
        $(function () {
            $('.jquibutton').hover(
                function () { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); },
                function () { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
            );
        });
    </script>-->
    <style type="text/css">
    #containerfooter {
        text-align: center;
        background-color:white;
        margin:0 auto 0 auto;
        width: 960px;
        color:black;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        font-family: "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
        padding: 0px 0 0px 0;
    }

    #containerfooter > div {
        border-right:dotted black 1px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        /* IE fix. */
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
        padding:0px 15px 10px 15px;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        text-align:left;
    }

    #containerfooter:after {
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    (!XmlPackage Name="skin.adminalert.xml.config"!)
    (!PAGEINFO!)
    <div id="pageWrap">
    <div id="headerWrap" class="box">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="topwrap">
                <div id="accountLinks">
                    <span id="loginText"><a href="(!SIGNINOUT_LINK!)">(!SIGNINOUT_TEXT!)</a></span> <a href="shoppingcart.aspx">View Cart</a> <a href="account.aspx">View Account</a>
                </div>
                <a id="logo" href="default.aspx" title="Saiedmusic.com">
                    (!Topic name="template.logo"!)
                </a>
                <div id="searchWrap">
                        <form name="topsearchform" method="get" action="search.aspx">
                        <input type="text" size="10" name="SearchTerm" id="searchBox" value="Enter Keywords" onclick="javascript: this.value = ''"/>
                        <input type="button" onclick="document.topsearchform.submit()" id="searchGo" value="Search" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <%--uncomment for multi language
                    <div id="ml">
                    <div style="visibility: (!COUNTRYDIVVISIBILITY!); display: (!COUNTRYDIVDISPLAY!);">
                        Language: (!COUNTRYSELECTLIST!)</div>
                    <div style="visibility: (!CURRENCYDIVVISIBILITY!); display: (!CURRENCYDIVDISPLAY!);">
                        Currency: (!CURRENCYSELECTLIST!)</div>
                    <div style="visibility: (!VATDIVVISIBILITY!); display: (!VATDIVDISPLAY!);">
                        VAT Mode: (!VATSELECTLIST!)</div>
                </div>--%>
                <div>
                                        (!XmlPackage Name="topNav.xml.config"!)
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentcontainer">
    <div id="pageWrap">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="bodyWrap">                

                <div id="homecontainer">      
                   <!-- CONTENTS START -->
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PageContent" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                <!-- CONTENTS END -->


                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>

                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="containerfooter" class="box clear">
                     (!topic name="template.footer"!)

            </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
        });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request to `superfish.js` returns HTML content instead of the JavaScript.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had linked the wrong file from the superfish-master.zip file. I went and re-uploaded everything and it worked just fine.